# I want to make this json in table form in dynamic way, how can i make it in android?

Tags: java, android, json

```
String jsonData="{\"sem1\" :[{\"subname\":\"TOC\",\"subcode\":\"1009\",\"subcredit\":\"6\",\"subgrade\":\"AB\"},{\"subname\":\"DS\",\"subcode\":\"10090\",\"subcredit\":\"5\",\"subgrade\":\"BB\"},{\"subname\":\"TOC\",\"subcode\":\"1009\",\"subcredit\":\"6\",\"subgrade\":\"AB\"}],\"sem2\":[{\"subname\":\"AAS\",\"subcode\":\"111009\",\"subcredit\":\"6\",\"subgrade\":\"AB\"},{\"subname\":\"AE\",\"subcode\":\"103309\",\"subcredit\":\"6\",\"subgrade\":\"DD\"}]}";
```

Here is My Code :

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... params1) {

        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsondata);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Iterator<String> iter = jsonObject.keys();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String key = iter.next();

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(key);
                int length = jsonArray.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    subname = jsonObject1.getString("subname");
                    subcode = jsonObject1.getString("subcode");
                    subcredit = jsonObject1.getString("subcredit");
                    subgrade = jsonObject1.getString("subgrade");

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain briefly,right now it's unclear what's you are asking for

Comment: actually i want to show this json in one UI, but this data is generate dynamically, it is for only one student this data is vary for other, then how can i handle this data dynamically.

Comment: could you understand what i trying to say is ?

Comment: not clearly understand what is your actual problem,is it the problem with updating the UI or parsing the dynamic json data.

Comment: this data is for only one student with its semester, suppose i create thi ui with this data then if other student data is does not match withi this fields then my app is crash, so i am trying to make one dynamic ui with java coding.

Comment: Ok now i understand,can you show me another json,i want to see how far different it is

Comment: In this scenario  no of semester and sub  is increase and, and i wants to show then in table layout, so how can i handle then dynamically.

Comment: Can you post post your xml buddy

Comment: i am giving you a link of my json.

Answer (score 0):

create a listview and add values to it.

```
 private List<YourListcontainer> listContainer = new ArrayList<YourListcontainer>();
```

Get your json values and add it in yourListContainer.

```
 MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter();
 Listview lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvid);
 lv.setAdapter(adapter); 

 private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<YourListcontainer> {

    public MyListAdapter() {
        // calls the base class constructor.
        super(context, R.layout.list_adapter, listContainer);
```

// context,resources,object

```
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemview = convertView;
        LayoutInflater listView = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (itemview == null) {
            itemview = listView.inflate(R.layout.list_adapter,
                    parent, false);
        }
        final YourListContainer item = listContainer.get(position);// returns the index of the cell
        TextView subject = (TextView) itemview
                .findViewById(R.id.txvsubject);
        subject.setText(item.getSubjectname());
        TextView code= (TextView) itemview
                .findViewById(R.id.txvcode);
        code.setText(item.getCode());
        TextView credit = (TextView) itemview
                .findViewById(R.id.txvcredit );
        credit .setText(item.getCredit ());
        TextView grade = (TextView) itemview
                .findViewById(R.id.txvgrade );
        grade .setText(item.getGrade ());


            subject.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borderstyle);
            code.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borderstyle);
            credit.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borderstyle);
            grade.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borderstyle);


        return itemview;
    }

}
```

Note: These border style is for draw your border.xml in table form like box type .